# New Lenovo Windows 10 Intel core i3-5020u 8gb ram

Tags: lenovo-laptop

It may not be the best laptop to get but I got it just for school. I got it about a week ago and used it for school only, such as for research and Windows office. Lately for two days now the laptop has been really sluggish. It started when I would plug in the charger, it would start to lag but as soon as I unplugged it it would go back to normal. Then it was just sluggish no matter what. I checked the task manager and come to find that 5gb of the ram is being used out of 8gb I don't think that's right with a new laptop, what can I do??? Please help!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the task manager processes? 5GB out of the 8GB is certainly unreasonable for a laptop being used for schoolwork. Can you also confirm the processor usage %?

Comment: It's possible that a lot of that 5GB is compressed/prefetched data and nothing to worry about, but some further details would be helpful.

Comment: @AaronLayfield Not so unreasonable. Modern browsers can use a lot of memory, depending on the pages you visit - a lot of deceptively simple pages are actually very RAM-hungry. (looking at you, dodgy mainstream news sites, facebook, etc...)

Comment: @Bob I don't disagree that modern browsers are the equivalent to Microsoft SQL Server in trying to hog the RAM. But, 5GB? That's definitely unreasonable, even for Chrome. RAM usage won't be the sluggish problem anyway, it'll be whatever is hogging the users processors.